# XCTAssertNotNil does nothing in Swift 2

Tags: swift, xctest

In my newly created Xcode 7.3.1 project I've got a test case that looks like so:

```swift
func testDatePicker_configuredCorrectly() {
    if vc.datePicker == nil {
        print("Date picker is nil")
    }
    XCTAssertNotNil(vc.datePicker, "Date picker must be linked")
}
```

When I run my test, I clearly see the console saying "Date picker is nil" and yet the assertion does not trigger.   The picker is just a normal outlet:

```swift
final class UsageViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: NSDatePicker!
}
```

Why is the assert for not nil being ignored?

Comment: This is possibly a race condition. What result do you get if the XCTAssertNotNil call is at the top of your test func? Are you familiar with `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout()`?

Comment: I found that this fails if the view is not yet loaded.  When I forced the view to load (as I should have done originally), then suddenly it started doing the proper assertion there.  I'm going to open a bug with Apple.

Comment: I spent ages on the same question. Then I found this `self.continueAfterFailure = NO`.  You set this in the Unit Test's  `- (void)setUp` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your test has a race condition, because it depends on the state of `vc` which is managed outside the scope of this test. You can either force the view to load as you stated, or set up a predicate expectation.

Comment: In the example I showed you're correct.  The "if" actually causes the view to load, and then the assert works.  Strange thing is if I leave out the if, it still passes.  I'll keep playing.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest possible example for `XCTAssertNotNil` works for me:

[image]

Try to add a breakpoint in the test code and only run this one test.